why i have this problem with this Nuget package
I have created a new project on visual studio .net maui.
I´m trying to install the NugetPackage CommunityToolkit.Maui version 9.01
enter image description here
But when I install it, an errors appears and I have to unistall it.
enter image description here
I don´t have any other package installed. The first thing I do is to install this package.
If i install the 8.0.0 version i have the same errors.
But if I install 7.0.1 version it works.
Can anyone tell me why this problem happen?
Thanks
Know the cause of this problem

Edit your project file (Double-click)
Replace matching/Add missing PackageReference with the following
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core" Version="9.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.40" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.40" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

